# Spring + Junit run integration tests in parallel

Tags: spring, junit, integration-testing, e2e-testing, parallel-testing

Currently we run integration/e2e tests using Spring+Junit and one database. We want to run tests faster, so we want to run tests in parallel.

How to configure Spring+Junit to run tests in parallel for example using 2 databases?

We are using Maven.

Comment: What versions of Spring and JUnit do you use?

Comment: @Anton Spring 5 + JUnit 5

Answer (score 0):

**Junit4**

`ParallelComputer`:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    JUnitCore.runClasses(new ParallelComputer(true, true), new Class<?>[]{Test1.class, Test2.class});
}
```

Extended `Suite.class`:

```
public class ParallelSuite extends Suite {

    public ParallelSuite(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass, builder);
        super.setScheduler(new RunnerScheduler() {

            private final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(klass.getAnnotation(SuiteClasses.class).value().length);

            @Override
            public void schedule(Runnable runnable) {
                service.submit(runnable);
            }

            @Override
            public void finished() {
                service.shutdown();
                try {
                    service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
    }

}
```

**JUnit5**

Highly experimental API which did not work for me. However may be it will be ok for you:
https://jitpack.io/#junit-team/junit5/experiments%7Eparallel-execution-SNAPSHOT
https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/60